# android google map marker already clicked on

Tags: android, google-maps

I have a Listview, if someone tapped on one of the entries he well be taken to another activity with a map, that map has a marker in the center, if you tap the marker it will show additional information about the place.

Is there a way to make the marker activated so that the user can read the info without them having to tap the marker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use the InfoWindow and make it visible all the time so the user doesn't have to click on the marker to see the infoWindow :

```
static final LatLng myPosition = new LatLng(0.0, 0.0);
Marker myMarker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                      .position(myPosition)
                      .title("My Position"));
                      .snippet("Any additional informations"));
myMarker.showInfoWindow();
```